# Pre-clone / pre-init git hooks?

Tags: bash, git

I am trying to figure out how best to write a "pre-init" or "pre-clone" hook. I'd be using it for students who are just learning git -- some kind of script that checks parent directories all the way up before actually performing the initiation or cloning of a repo.

I know there are a number of pre-[action] hooks available in git, but at the repository level, not a global level. Is there a way to create a hook like this, or am I better off writing an alias of some kind? I read through the documentation and it seems to hint that this type of thing is possible but wasn't specific about how.

**UPDATE:** I ended up creating a couple of aliases. Here they are. If anyone has suggestions on how to make them better, I'm definitely interested -- bash scripting is not my area of expertise.

```
is_git_repo() {
    $(git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree &> /dev/null)
}

is_git_dir() {
    $(git rev-parse --is-inside-git-dir 2> /dev/null)
}

check_for_git_repo() {
  if is_git_repo || is_git_dir; then
    echo "You are currently in a git repository. Please leave this repository and try again."
    return 1
  fi
}

check_for_git_parent() {
  if tree -a -d | grep -q '.git'; then
    echo "This directory is not a git repository, but one of its subdirectories is. Please create a new subdirectory and try again."
    return 1
  fi
}

alias ginit='check_for_git_repo && check_for_git_parent && echo "Creating repository" && git init'

gclone() {
  check_for_git_repo && git clone $*
}
```

Comment: You will need an alias or a script. `git init` will copy a set of *default* hooks (from the template directory specified as an option, or the default template directory) to a newly-created repository. `git clone` effectively runs `git init` so it does the same thing. However, the copying happens *after* creating the `.git` directory, which sounds like it's too late for whatever it is you have in mind (you have not actually mentioned what that is).

Comment: @torek ahhh I got you. Yeah, that does sound like it would be too late for what I want. (Which is: check current directory for .git, check parent directory for .git, keep going down the directory tree until we get to the root. If at any point there is a .git, exit without initiating the repository.)